# Why was my useful edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16842487

My edit makes a simple grammar fix of a sentence that is otherwise grammatically ***invalid***. The edit was rejected, however, by two people. I don't agree with the reasons they gave at all. Could anyone suggest what's wrong with the edit?

Comment: Yes it's useful, but only ever so slightly. But in the big scheme of things, really how important is this?

Comment: Even without that edit the post is still readable and has been since 2008. I personally wonder if *become* is even correct there but I'm not a native speaker. If there is only one small mistake to fix I would be very hesitant to make such edits as your edits needs to be reviewed. Better focus on the new posts that come in and need spelling, grammar, code formatting and the removal of fluff. Much better spend time, by you and for the reviewers.

Comment: @rene Is there anything wrong about making it slightly more readable? Why spend the time to reject a useful edit? That's completely irrational and harmful behavior.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy to look at it from the other side, why submit such a minimal edit given that multiple people will have to spend time to review it? Try to make more substantive contributions.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy Yes, there is.  You're consuming the time of several reviewers, bumping the post, taking up a position in the queue until your edit is reviewed, preventing other edits (that would actually be useful) from being suggested, preventing that post from being edited while your edit is pending, rewarding you for a behavior that's not actually helpful, etc.  Edits have a cost, particularly when they require review from others.  If you want to suggest edits, make sure they're actually useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The rejection reason says: "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible." But that's a complete lie! I had to reread the sentence when I ran across the answer, which is what happens when you're reading a grammatically incorrect sentence. My edit clearly makes the answer easier to read.

Comment: @Servy My edit was actually useful. Given that I made the edit already, why would anyone reject it? It clearly adds value. Is that a way of discouraging people from participation? "I don't like to waste my time reviewing edits that don't invent a cure for cancer, so I'll waste my time rejecting a useful edit"? Is that the reasoning?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy I don't see it as being useful, and neither did the people that rejected it, which is why they rejected it.  *You* think it adds value, they disagreed.  A cure for cancer would be great, but the bar is slightly lower than that, you just need to suggest edits that add more value than they cost.  It's not hard to do.

Comment: @Servy You don't see why a correction of an obviously grammatically incorrect sentence is useful?

Comment: @Servy Being a reviewer, if you agree to review my edit, why would you decide to destroy value instead of add value?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy I don't see your correction as an obviously correct correction, no.  If you're going to suggest an edit, why would you decide to suggest one that's not of value, instead of suggesting one that *is*?

Comment: @Servy Wow, now my comments are disappearing.

Comment: @Servy you might as well write an answer as I can't find an appropriate dupe. The closest I could find was [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284255/is-a-superfluous-edit-really-a-reason-to-reject-it)

Comment: Just throwing this out there: if the grammatical mistake was that bad, why did nobody think to edit it in the nine years it's been live?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy: We force people to make significant changes because we don't want people farming rep by finding typos. Approved edits are worth 2 rep until you get universal editing privileges, and we only want to give rep for things that actually matter.

Comment: What's happening here is that you have your own idea about how edits (in particular, suggested edits) work on Stack Overflow, and we're trying to tell you how edits *actually* work on Stack Overflow. There are good reasons for the way edits actually work that have been arrived at over many years, so please consider that before throwing around words like "toxic".

Comment: @NicolBolas When you say "we", who are you referring to?

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy The community, I imagine.

Comment: @Rob The community of people that oppose fixing a glaring typo on a post with over 1 million views? http://imgur.com/a/805pX

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy I never mentioned my stance on the issue; just clarifying what *I* took to mean their meaning of 'we' to be. Though Nicol does raise a good point about people deliberately making trivial edits in order to gain reputation (and thus privileges)

Comment: By the way, the typo was **introduced** by the following edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15389473

Comment: @NicolBolas Can someone from the privileged community fix the typo? I'm ok with not earning 2 rep on that.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy: "*The community of people that oppose fixing a glaring typo on a post with over 1 million views?*" No, the community of people that oppose letting people gain 2 rep from fixing a typo.

Comment: *I personally wonder if become is even correct there...* @rene It wasn't. Rob's edit added the word "are" which is correct.

Comment: @BSMP: Both are correct, depending on whether the verb is intended to parallel "go" or "will go".

Comment: @BSMP evil minds might think that it had to be *become* because only that is 6 letters, the minimal for an edit to go through anyway....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override the rejection of a legitimate edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348219/how-to-override-the-rejection-of-a-legitimate-edit)

Comment: By the way @Rob ended up fixing the issue that my edit targeted. I thanked him here, but someone deleted my comment. Similarly my other comments in this discussion were removed without notice or explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a perpetual problem, unfortunately, and has been ever since the suggested edits system was invented.

The issue is, as has already been explained to you in the comments, that the reviewers felt your edit was *too minor*. In other words, they thought the edit was *trivial* and did not *substantially improve* the post. Therefore, they rejected it. That's a completely valid reason to reject an edit, but it is obviously a subjective one. Different reviewers will and do have different standards for what makes an edit "substantial".

Naturally, the next question is, why are trivial edits bad? The answer (again, as has already been revealed in the comments) is two-fold:

1. You are awarded reputation points when your suggested edit is approved, so submitting a rash of excessively trivial edits is a form of reputation farming and widely considered to be a relatively inappropriate (if not downright abusive) way of gaining reputation (and therefore, most importantly, privileges on the site).
2. Suggested edits have to be reviewed and approved by at least two other trusted users. The idea is, this is a reasonable use of their time as long as the edits are substantially improving the site for everyone. However, if the edits are trivial, this is wasting the time of those two reviewers, who could have been spending that time doing other things to improve the site (posting answers, making edits of their own, etc.).

Your edit was not *wrong*, and it's easy to imagine that had two *different* people reviewed it, it would have been approved. At the same time, the rejection *was* valid—I can certainly see how someone would consider this too trivial (and I'm quite a stickler about grammar). Hopefully you can now understand their perspective, too.

What can you do about this going forward? You really only have three options:

1. Only submit edits where you are making substantial revisions to the post. In other words, only make edits that are *obviously* non-trivial.
2. If you want to make what would otherwise be a trivial edit like this one, go through the rest of the post with a fine-toothed comb and fix any other trivial problems that might be there. In this case, there are a couple of commas omitted and a couple of phrases (like *"Stores local data, return addresses, used for parameter passing"*) that don't make sense and should be rewritten.

   The idea here is, by making a large number of trivial edits, the entire edit is no longer trivial.

   Note, though, that this only works well for those with exceptional English skills. If you're not a native speaker, or struggled in English grammar courses, you will probably just end up doing more harm than good if you try to do this. Best to leave it for someone else to handle.
3. Insist that your edit was reasonable (as I said above, you do have a leg to stand on) and keep suggesting edits like this one, taking your chances with the reviewers. Some of them will get approved; some of them will get rejected. I'm not too sure what your odds are of approval vs. rejection, and this is risky because too many rejected edits will temporarily ban you from making additional suggestions.

Comment: "Your edit was not wrong" I wouldn't even say that.  It used the wrong tense, making the edited version incorrect.

Comment: @Servy Not true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Cody!

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy And why is that?

Comment: @Servy Because I used the right tense, making the edited version a grammatically correct, legible sentence.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy But you used the wrong tense, making the edited version a grammatically incorrect, illegible sentence.

Comment: @Servy Can you make an actual argument, please?

Comment: I don't see how the edit used the wrong tense. The "and" is potentially confusing here, so leave it out and re-read the sentence: "Variables created on the stack…become automatically deallocated." That looks correct to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @CodyGray It doesn't become automatically deallocated in the future.  It's a property that has always, and currently is, true, for that object.  It doesn't "become" automatically deallocated later, it *is* automatically deallocated ("are" in the sentence in question, as it's pluralized there).